# Setting default shape menus in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When starting a new drawing I always have to go through the process of closing the ones I don't need and opening the ones I do. I would like to cut this step from my process.

Is there a way to set the shape menus I want in draw.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there's a URL parameter libs that takes a semicolon separated list of the library sets you want, e.g.:

```
https://www.draw.io/?libs=general;flowchart;basic;arrows;clipart;signs;mockups;electrical;aws;pid;leanMapping;cisco
```

That's also the list of all possible values currently for that parameter. You've made me realise there's a bug with ER, BPMN and iOS sets regarding this, we'll look at that.

We have discussed this and intend to persist the library settings between uses. A question for you, would you prefer this to be stored per browser (i.e. cookies) or per Google account (as a meta file in your Drive)?

Comment: Thank you so much! Also ER and iOS does not show up in the "Show more..." list.

I would personally prefer a meta file in the Google Drive but not everyone will use Google Drive so a cookie is most flexible. Maybe the cookie is the fall back?